# PDFBox Get PDF Orientation not as expected

Tags: java, pdfbox

Tryng to get PDF orientation to calculated coordinates of signature image, have 2 PDF with same width and height but the orientation not same, this the line of code to get height and width

```
PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);
PDRectangle pageRect = page.getCropBox();
System.out.println("Width page " + pageRect.getWidth());
System.out.println("Height page " + pageRect.getHeight());
```

sample of PDF

[0 degree](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1ca9e15gpx3ze14/doc0.pdf?dl=0)

[180 degree](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ldmi71ut7wx7gql/doc180.pdf?dl=0)

define coordinates of signature on pdf 0 degree :

```
float lx = (float) 300;
float ly = (float) 278;
float rx = (float) 442;
float ry = (float) 349;
Rectangle2D humanRect = new Rectangle2D.Float(lx, ry, rx - lx, ry - ly);

float x = (float) humanRect.getX();


float width = (float) humanRect.getWidth();
float height = (float) humanRect.getHeight();

PDPage page = doc.getPage(0);

PDRectangle pageRect = page.getCropBox();
LogSystem.info("Width page " + pageRect.getWidth());
LogSystem.info("Height page " + pageRect.getHeight());

float pageWidth = (float) pageRect.getWidth();
float pageHeigth = (float) pageRect.getHeight();

PDRectangle rect = new PDRectangle();

float y = pageRect.getHeight() - (float)humanRect.getY();

int orientation = page.getRotation();

// signing should be at the same position regardless of page rotation.

switch (orientation)
{
        case 90:
            rect.setLowerLeftY(x);
            rect.setUpperRightY(x + width);
            rect.setLowerLeftX(y);
            rect.setUpperRightX(y + height);
            break;
        case 180:
            rect.setUpperRightX(pageWidth - x);
            rect.setLowerLeftX(pageWidth - x - width);
            rect.setLowerLeftY(y);
            rect.setUpperRightY(y + height);
            break;
        case 270:
            rect.setLowerLeftY(pageHeigth - x - width);
            rect.setUpperRightY(pageHeigth - x);
            rect.setLowerLeftX(pageWidth - y - height);
            rect.setUpperRightX(pageWidth - y);
            break;
        case 0:
        default:
            rect.setLowerLeftX(x);
            rect.setUpperRightX(x + width);
            rect.setLowerLeftY(pageHeigth - y - height);
            rect.setUpperRightY(pageHeigth - y);
            break;
    }
    LogSystem.info("Rect"+rect);

    return rect;
```

the algorithm switch from createSignatureRectacle on CreateVisibleSignature2.java

in PDF 0 degree position of signature was exactly as expected, but with the PDF 180 degree the signature was not exactly expected, this why the signature not precision. Why the result of get orientation not same ? and how to handle it ?

or can i specify coordinates ignoring orientation (assume document orientation is always 0 degrees) ?

Comment: the link has been changed

Comment: I ran both documents with CreateVisibleSignature2.java from the trunk and it worked nicely, i.e. both looked identical. (There is a difference, which is the rotation, you can see it with PDFDebugger)  So my suggestion is that you get CreateVisibleSignature2.java to work, and then modify that one to your needs, and find where it "breaks".

Comment: yes the rectangle i was success to right coordinate, but image in the rectangle be Stretch

Comment: I have to readjust the image

Comment: anyone tryng text in the rectangle got stretch ? how to handle ? cs.showText(title);

Comment: According to your comments you now have different issues. Thus, you may want to adapt your question to these different issues. As there is no actual answer here, such editing won't render any answer useless.

Comment: I'm completely lost. Please create a new question from scratch.